# Azure DevOps pass/fail build based on performance regressions

Tags: azure-devops, performance-testing, benchmarkdotnet

For a new project, I want to keep track of application performance by using BenchmarkDotNet to build up the performance testing suite. Does anyone know if there is anything already built to pass/fail an Azure DevOps build based on the performance results? For example, if a performance test is suddenly three times slower than the previous run I want to fail the build. I've heard some teams keep running metrics of performance but have never heard of how to go about setting something like that up.

I see that with BenchmarkDotNet I can export the results. But I'm hoping there is already something that exists, instead of having to create my own solution to this.

Comment: I think this can be a great addition to my company project as well. Strange that there is no other information about it